# How can I enlarge the size of text on the printout of a PDF?

Tags: pdf, printing

I have a few PDF files, for instance [this one](http://prapatti.com/slokas/tamil/sudarshanasahasranaamam.pdf), which are in the Tamil language, and I want to print them out.  Unfortunately, when I just print them out normally, the text is too small for my grandfather to read, so I want to enlarge the text somehow.  I can't copy the text and paste it in word, because it's in Tamil script.  And when I try to increase the scaling in the print dialog, what it does is it divides a given page both horizontally and vertically into sectors, and then prints each sector, enlarged, in a similar page.  Clearly that's undesirable behavior when you have lines of text, because you're cutting off a line of text at an arbitrary place, like the middle of a word or even the middle of a letter.

So my question is, is there any way to divide the page into horizontal strips instead?  That way you don't break in the middle of a line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: do you have Acrobat XI?

Comment: or another pdf editor? something like 'Foxit Advanced PDF Editor' or 'PDF Complete Office Edition'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a program that does what I want, which is divide a page only into horizontal strips.  It's called [A-PDF Page Cut](http://www.a-pdf.com/page-cut/), which is a paid software, but I downloaded the free trial and at first glance the only limitation seems to be that it puts a watermark on the top of the first page.

What you do is you just place horizontal and/or vertical lines on a page, and it will cut it into separate pages.  So I took the PDF I linked to and put a horizontal line in the middle of each page, and then I opened the new PDF in my PDF reader and printed it in landscape mode, using the "fit to page" option to enlarge the size of the text.  So to sum up, an 8.5 by 11 page became two 8.5 by 5.5 pages, and each such page was enlarged to fit on an 11 by 8.5 landscape piece of paper, so the text size was basically doubled.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a pdf editor like [Acrobat XI](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat.html) or [Foxit Advanced PDF Editor](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/PDF_Editor/) or you can convert the file to a word doc using something like [nitro cloud](https://www.nitrocloud.com/).

Comment: Is there any free software to do this?

Comment: I think nitro cloud is free, Foxit also.

Comment: I just tried Nitro, but it's not properly extracting the text from my PDF because it's in Tamil script.  As far as Acrobat goes, the description here: http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/scale-or-resize-printed-pages.html it doesn't mention dividing the page into horizontal strips, it's only about dividing the page both horizontally and vertically, which I can already do in just a regular PDF reader.  Do you know whether Foxit has the option to only split the page into horizontal strips?

Comment: Page 124 of the manual for Foxit doesn't describe dividing the page into horizontal strips either: http://cdn01.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/manual/enu/FoxitAdvancedEditor30_Manual.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Not free software, but VeryPDF's [PDFPrint Command Line](http://www.verypdf.com/pdfprint/pdf-print-cmd.html) can do this. I tried it with the sample PDF you provided, and the font is larger, although pixelated. The command I used was:

```
pdfprint.exe -firstpage 1 -lastpage 1 -paper letter -scale 125 -paper letter sudarshanasahasranaamam.pdf
```

But for some reason it kept asking for the paper size. I didn't use `-paper pdf` so your mileage may vary with that one.

Comment: Does it divide the page only into horizontal strips, or does it divide it both horizontally and vertically?